# changecolor function not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, image, function, slider

I have tried several variations but can't seem to get this function to manipulate the color of some circles,that are part of a image slider.It needs to work upon the clicking of the next arrow.I added the next function myself and that works perfectly,but it has a button of its own.
Any help would be appreciated.

here is the javascript...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Sidelines In The Ulvestad</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="flow.css" >
  <script type="text/javascript">
```

var currentPhoto = 0;
var pics = new Array();

```
window.onload=function() {
 for (var i =0; i< 10; i++) {
  pics[i] = new Image();

}

pics[0].src = "ulvestadside.png";
pics[1].src = "usl2.png";
pics[2].src = "usl3.png";
pics[3].src = "usl4.png";
pics[4].src = "usl5.png";
pics[5].src = "usl6.png";
pics[6].src = "usl7.png";
pics[7].src = "usl8.png";
pics[8].src = "usl9.png";



document.getElementById("next").onclick=nextPic;
document.getElementById("prev").onclick=prevPic;
document.getElementById("reset").onclick=reSet;


}

function changePhoto(photo)  {

document.images[0].src = pics[photo].src;
}
```

function nextPic() {

```
 currentPhoto++;
 changecolor();
 if(currentPhoto < pics.length) {
 changePhoto(currentPhoto);
  }else{
  reSet();


}
}





function prevPic() {

  if (currentPhoto >0) {
  currentPhoto--;
  changePhoto(currentPhoto);
}

}







function reSet() {

document.images[0].src = pics[0].src;
 currentPhoto = 0;

  }

 function changecolor() {

var col = document.getElementById("small")col.style.backgroundColor = "red";

 }

 </script>
```

here is the relevent html...

```
 <div class="wrapper4">


  <div class ="post2f">



<img src="ulvestadside.png">

<div id ="next"> <img src ="arrow3.png"> </div>

<div id ="prev"><img src = "arrow4.png"> </div>

 <button id = "reset"> reset</button>

<div id ="small"> </div>

<div id ="small1"> </div>

<div id ="small2"> </div>

<div id ="small3"> </div>

<div id ="small4"> </div>

<div id ="small5"> </div>

<div id ="small6"> </div>

<div id ="small7"> </div>

</div>

 </div>

</body> 
</html>
```

and here is the css....

```
#small {

position:absolute; 
top:390px;
left:50px;  
background-color:black;
 height: 10px;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
width: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's this?

```
var col = document.getElementById("small")col.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

Shouldn't it be something like this?

```
document.getElementById("small").style.backgroundColor = "red";
```